# javascript run function on update of cell

Tags: javascript, primefaces, datatable, execute

I have a javascript function inside a primefaces datatable and want to run it every time the row has been updated. I'm updating the row via omnifaces.

eg.

```
<p:dataTable>
  <p:column>
    <script>
      function doSomething(){
        console.debug('do');  // re-execute everytime the row or column has been updated.
      }
    </script>
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

does anyone have an idea how to archeive this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to run the JS 'oncomplete' of the ajax cell edit.  Similar to:

`<p:dataTable>
    <p:ajax event="cellEdit" oncomplete="foo.doSomething()" />
</p:dataTable>`

Comment: thanks for your answer WitYoBadSelf, but `<p:ajax event="cellEdit" oncomplete="console.debug('update')" />` is not called when I update a row/cell. Maybe I should mention that I update it via Omifaces's Ajax.update.